# Sagemaker export and load model to memory

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have created a model using sagemaker (on aws ml notebook). 
I then exported that model to s3 and a `.tar.gz` file was created there.

Im trying to find a way to load the model object to memory in my code (without using AWS docker images and deployment) and run a prediction on it.

I looked for functions to do that in the model section of the [sagemaker docs](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/model.html#), but everything there is tightly coupled to the AWS docker images.

I then tried opening the file with `tarfile` and `shutil` packages but that was useless.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which algorithm did you use to train your model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the exception of XGBoost, built-in algorithms are implemented with Apache MXNet, so simply extract the model from the .tar.gz file and load it with MXNet: load_checkpoint() is the API to use.

XGBoost models are just pickled objects. Unpickle and load in sklearn:

```
$ python3
>>> import sklearn, pickle
>>> model = pickle.load(open("xgboost-model", "rb"))
>>> type(model)
<class 'xgboost.core.Booster'>
```

Models trained with built-in library (Tensorflow, MXNet, Pytorch, etc.) are vanilla models that can be loaded as-is with the correct library.

Hope this helps.